# Same entry deletion in multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a 3D array of shape `(10,10,10)`. I put some random float numbers inside this cube from 0 to 1. I do this several times, so I have multiple 3D arrays (let's say 50), i.e. a total shape of my new 4D array of `(50,10,10,10)`.

What I now wish to do is to look in every of the 50 single cubes and locate all 0's and all 1's. If it either exists/is found in any entry of the 50 3D arrays, that particular entry should be deleted from all 50 3D arrays.

So basically, if 1 is found in the first 3D array in entry `(5,6,7)` this entry should be deleted/removed from ALL 3D arrays and so on.

I was hoping there would be some numpy tricks for this. But I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: What do you mean "delete/remove"? Can you give a minimal example?

Comment: If you remove an entry from a `cube`, what's the new shape of the cube?  Step back from your 4d array, and think about removing an element from a simpler 2d array, such as `np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)`.  Remove the [1,2] element.  What's the remaining array going to look like?

Comment: Yes, I kind of came to the same conclusion when I tried to update the OP with an example. It made much more sense before I wrote it out. I did however find an alternative solution.